# I switched to Catalina and enabled ZSH now my home/end key do not work in terminal

Tags: terminal, bash, catalina, zsh

I switched to ZSH from BASH as per the upgrade in Catalina and all is well except my home/end keys no longer work.  This can be really annoying trying to move my cursor over super far to the left instead of a single home  click.

Any idea if they just changed the key you use to "go to start of command" instead of home? Or is there a bug?

Comment: Note that Ctrl-A and Ctrl-E does this (emacs bindings).

Answer (score 32):

The other answers didn't work for me when connecting over SSH to the Mac. I had to add the following lines to my `~/.zshrc` to get Home and End to work:

```
bindkey "^[[H" beginning-of-line
bindkey "^[[F" end-of-line
```

Comment: It also works in Linux. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

@jemcclin's answer did not work for me. Here's what worked for me on latest `macOS Catalina 10.15.5`

1. Open Terminal -> Preferences...
2. Select your preferred profile
3. On the Keyboard tab, add a new binding (or modify an existing one)
4. Use the following settings to make Home work again:

   - Key: Home (↖)
   - Modifier: None
   - Action: Send Text
   - Text to send is `\001` (CTRL+A)
5. Use the following settings to fix the End key:

   - Key: End (↗)
   - Modifier: None
   - Action: Send Text
   - Text to send is `\005` (CTRL+E)

Extra: btw, i was having the same Home/"Scroll to top" issues on webpage forms (like the one i'm typing right now to answer this) and what fixed for me was this

> https://www.iexplain.org/remap-home-and-end-buttons-for-external-keyboard-on-mac/

Answer (score 7):

It seems the control characters required for `zsh` in Terminal are slightly different than the ones that worked in `bash`.

To fix your Home/End keys:

1. Open Terminal -> Preferences...
2. Select your preferred profile
3. On the Keyboard tab, add a new binding (or modify an existing one)
4. Use the following settings to make Home work again:

   - Key: Home (↖)
   - Modifier: None
   - Action: Send Text
   - Text to send is `\033[1~` (For `bash`, `\033OH` was the value that worked)
5. Use the following settings to fix the End key:

   - Key: End (↗)
   - Modifier: None
   - Action: Send Text
   - Text to send is `\033[4~` (For `bash`, `\033OF` was value that worked)

This fixes my Home/End keys in `zsh`, and also works correctly when connected over SSH to terminals running `bash`.

Note that if you have keybindings specified in your `~/.zshrc` or are running a third-party software to adjust your keybindings globally (eg: Karabiner), you might need to check or undo any settings in those places that may affect the Home/End keys if you're getting weird behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

@jemcclin's answer requires the following entries in ~/.zshrc to work

```
bindkey "\e[1~" beginning-of-line
bindkey "\e[4~" end-of-line
```

Comment: Thanks! If you ever want to edit another answer to clarify, that’s encouraged as well as posting an answer.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I wasn't aware that answer-editing was a thing for novice users. But I'll consider that option if the need arises again. (I went for a 2nd answer, because my reputation was too low to add a simple comment)